# Android view animation on top of GLSurfaceView is slow

Tags: android, animation, view, glsurfaceview, compositing

We've noticed that when you put Android views with view animation (nothing complex, just AlphaAnimation and TranslateAnimation) on top of a GLSurfaceView, the animation runs slowly (i.e. you see a lot of stuttering.) I am calling pause() on the GLSurfaceView, and I believe I've confirmed (through setting breakpoints) that the GL draw calls are not getting hit while the animation is playing, so I'm not sure where the slowness is coming from.

Does anyone know of a way around this? I know that on iPhone this also used to be a problem, but there was some OS update they made to fix the issue. They are short view animations (e.g. You Win!) so it's not the worst thing in the world, but it would be nice if there was some workaround.

The reason we are not doing the animations in GL is that they have to be able to run from any Activity in our game, and not all of our Activities have GLSurfaceViews.

Finally, if it matters, we am using the modified GLSurfaceView source from Replica Island http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/

Answer (score 4):

Drawing on top of a GLSurfaceView is slow, therefore animating is as well. You are forcing the framework to do more work to determine what part of the surface view is visible.

You should really consider doing these animations inside the surface view when you are using a surface view.

An alternative is to put the animation in a small window above your activity.

Comment: By small window, do you mean spawn another activity with a dialog-sized window? Does the drawing code do something faster in that case?

Comment: Don't spawn an Activity, just a window (using WindowManager.)